# Cant find Hyper V on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am trying to develop an app on Visual Studios 2015. I have downloaded the Emulator needed to run windows phone app. However everytime I run the code this error message displays:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt25h.png)

I enabled Virtualisation in the BIOS but still nothing.

The Hyper-V also doesnt appear in  Program and Features - Turn Windows Feature On or Off.
[File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuI7g.png)

I tried installing Hyper-V by inputting a few commands using Powershell and  CMD but errors like 'file hasnt been found' were showing up. Is there an alternative to run a windows app in VisualStudios 15?, The Windows Phone 8 emulator is all downloaded. I want to develop the app in either VB or C#.

Comment: Have you considered the absolutely ridiculous fact that your version of Windows 10 may not have Hyper-V?

Comment: @TomTom Not really...I thought all laptops have Hyper-V and im working with the most updated windows 10.

Comment: @TomTom Say if my OS doesnt have Hyper -V , is there a way where I can make the emulator work?

Comment: Only Professional and Enterprise have it. If you have a lower one - yes, there is a way. Upgrade to Professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper-V is only available on Windows 10 Professional, Enterprise or Education. You are probably using Windows 10 Home edition.

Comment: According to this page, yes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_compatibility